# aws cli rm when wild cards are needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, rm

It says in docs for aws cli that wild cards are not supported. You can use --include and --exclude options. But that could take a while when files structure is wide.

```
aws s3 rm s3://your-bucket/your-folder/year=2020/month=05/ --exclude "*" --include "*/provider=400/qk=0001" --include "*/provider=400/qk=0002" --include "*/provider=400/qk=0003" --include "*/provider=400/qk=0010" ...
```

So what are other options?

Comment: What do you mean by "could take a while"? Do you mean it takes some time _before_ starting the deletions, or because it needs to delete so many objects? Or too long to write the command? Are you simply wanting to delete everything under `provider=400/`? If so, can't you just use `--include "*/provider=400/*"`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have 100 qk subkeys under provider=400, I need to delete 40 of them. --include and --exclude does listObjects (I assume), there are about 200 files for each qk, for one month that would take a while

Comment: If you need to be selective (eg only delete certain subfolders), then your method is good. Alternatively, you could a solution using the AWS SDK (eg a Python script) that would list the contents under a given Prefix and then use `delete_objects()`. Another method would be to configure an Amazon S3 Lifecycle rule to delete the objects, but I'm not sure if it can accept 40 different subfolders. Don't worry about the elapsed time to delete the objects -- you can run it overnight or even in parallel on several threads and instances. Welcome to Big Data!

Answer (score 0):

In shell terminal you can do next trick:

```
for i in `s3://your-bucket/your-folder/year=2020/month=05/day={01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10...}/provider=400/qk={0001,0002,0003,0010,...}; do aws s3 rm $i --recursive; done
```